# Finding files with certain extension

Tags: bash, shell

When trying to find certain files with certain extension for example .*c

If I input the code below

```
find folder1 -type f -name '*c'
```

the result comes up like

```
folder1/filename1.c

folder1/filename2.c
```

If I only want the file names, not including the directory to the file like below, how would i have to change the code?

```
filename1.c

filename2.c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) under the `-printf` option you'll see:

```
%f     File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).
```

To use it:

```
find folder1 -type f -name '*.c' -printf '%f\n'
```

---

<sup>P.S. Careful with the pattern. You want `*.c`, not `.*c` or `*c`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe it to an `awk` command like this

```
find folder1 -type f -name '*.c' | awk -F '/' '{ print $NF }'
```